How to include source tex file name in aux and output directory paths with latexmk?
Let's say I have three directories src, aux-dir, and out-dir, all in the same workspace directory work, and some independent but similarly formatted files bleb1.tex, bleb2.tex, ... sitting in src. I'd like to configure latexmk to compile some bleb<i>.tex into bleb<i>.pdf such that the auxiliary files are written into a subdirectory bleb<i> of aux-dir, and the output files (e.g. bleb<i>.pdf) are written to a subdirectory bleb<i> of out-dir. Since there are going to be many bleb<i>.tex files, I'd like to avoid needing to create these subdirectories manually before the first time I compile each bleb<i>.tex.
I've defined a custom latexmk configuration file in work towards this end. I know that within a configuration file, the aux files destination and output files destination can be specified via the variables $aux_dir and $out_dir, respectively, and that latexmk is even so convenient as to create the paths specified in the variables if they do not already exist. However, what I don't know is how to get the subdirectory names to depend on the base name bleb<i> of the source .tex file.
It doesn't appear that any of the placeholder variables %A, %R, etc... are accessible in the configuration file outside of overwriting a command variable (e.g. $latex = "latex %O %S"). My first attempt was to change $latex to internal mylatex %A to access the source file name and insert it into $aux_dir and $out_dir within my own mylatex subroutine. My second attempt was to try setting $aux_dir and $out_dir variables to a path containing the filename given by $$Pbase in a custom subroutine to be called on the before_xlatex hook. For both of these attempts, latexmk doesn't pick up on the changes to $aux_dir and $out_dir before vomitting all the aux and output files into work by default. The documentation for latexmk doesn't seem to specify how to access, in the configuration file, the command line arguments (in particular, the source file name) passed by latexmk in any other way. In my third attempt, instead of changing $aux_dir and $out_dir, I just tried to change the corresponding -aux-directory and -output-directory flags in a Perl system call I make to latex inside the mylatex subroutine from the first attempt, but, again, latexmk ignores these flags and just dumps files in work.
At this point I've realized that my original planned directory structure for work isn't ideal to begin with on account of possible issues that could arise with, say, bibtex, but I've spent enough time messing around trying to get the original plan to work that I'm curious to see if it's possible, or if I've misunderstood some fundamental design principle of latexmk.

This is the ideal use case for a Makefile.

At this point, what you are requesting isn't supported by latexmk.  It would be possible to implement it; this would entail a change of the code that latexmk uses before it starts to process a tex file.  At present
The attempts you made are all too late to do what's needed.  After the initialization is done for a given .tex file, the directories $aux_out and $out_dir need to remain fixed, and known to latexmk.
